# Remove lines in a shell script

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, scripting

I have this file:

```
# more file.txt
 2c2
lns-ld-wall-01-t2 old:261,260
4c4
Prive_ORANGE old:258,259
```

I need to remove  all lines like this one  `2c2` and this one  `4c4`. How can I do in a shell script?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed 's/.*[0-9]c[0-9].*//g' file.txt
```

However as mentioned in the comment, above command will not remove the complete lines, so a better way would be to use the `d` command on matching lines instead:

```
sed '/[0-9]c[0-9]/d' file.txt
```

Or with extended regular expressions with GNU `sed` (`-E` is the preferred flag for compatibility with BSD* `sed`s):

```
sed -E '/^[[:blank:]]*[0-9]+[a-z]+[0-9]/d' file
```

Comment: this will not remove  line, and will not work with `12c12` like lines.

Comment: @Archemar : Thanks. I've corrected the command.

Comment: Before providing answers let's wait and see what sie already tried. Nobody is expecting to spoon feed anybody.

Comment: Yes. I'll keep that in mind for future.

Comment: @shivams; In your second variant the `.*` are unnecessary. (And also consider Archemar's comment.)

Comment: `\+`, `\?` and `\t` are not POSIX. `-E` should be preferred over `-r` as it's supported by both GNU and some BSDs `sed` and is going to make it to the next version of the standard.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the suggestion. The answer has been modified, feel free to provide a more portable solution.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` (and `egrep` or its modern equivalent `grep -E`) is your friend:

```
man grep
```

See the `-v` option.

Here:

```
grep -Exv '[[:blank:]]*[0-9]+c[0-9]+[[:blank:]]*' file
```

would filter out lines consisting of `c` surrounded by decimal digits and optional blanks.

Comment: If you read the man page on `grep` you can see that using `egrep` is deprecated.

Comment: Mentioning `egrep` is certainly even unnecessary for the given question and doesn't contribute any necessary functionality. (Effectively `egrep` is anyway just `grep -E`.) That all said; Using `grep -v` is (compared with `sed`) certainly the more straightforward solution (so I don't think the "-1" is justified).

Comment: @Anthon: Sorry, I am not able to read **your** man page. I can only read **mine**. Now, seriously: I mentioned egrep in addition to grep because from the question (which gave just an **example** of strings to include), it might be that the OP wanted maybe have a **list** of pattern to be excluded. About the **obsoletedness**, this depends on which platform you are. On some platforms, -E is not supported. On some (mine for example), egrep is not mentioned as deprecated in the man-page. For this reason, I prefer egrep over grep -E (the scripts are more portable).

Answer (score 0):

Take the perl way.

Test with:

```
perl -ne 's/^\s*[0-9]+c[0-9]+$//g; if ($_ !~ /^$/) {print }' file.txt
```

Change the file `file.txt` with:

```
perl -ne 's/^\s*[0-9]+c[0-9]+$//g; if ($_ !~ /^$/) {print }' -i file.txt
```